# google adsense on ajax page

Tags: ajax, adsense

I using InstantClick to make my website instant.

it's amazing.

but, google adsense stopped working.

youtube also ajax, and youtube adsense always working.

how do they do it ?

thanks~

Comment: Adsense won't work with InstantClick. Because instant click works something like this. When you hover over the link/tab/button it gets the content at that moment itself and caches it in the browser for fast load up if you click on it.

Comment: @RohitBatra www.dmeng.net

Comment: Are you using InstantClick on this right now?